# Can not transform data using Xml to Jaxb Transformer : Mule Esb

Tags: xml, jaxb, mule, mule-component

I tried to transform my soap web service data.I used xml to Jaxb transformer...
But I got following error

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: An invalid return type
>   "class [B" was specified for transformer "JAXBMarshallerTransformer"
>     at
>   org.mule.module.xml.transformer.jaxb.JAXBMarshallerTransformer.doTransform(JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java:119)
>     at
>   org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:419)
>     at
>   org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:377)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

My flow is as follow

```
 <flow name="test123Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/student" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getAllStudentData" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="org.test.StudentDemo" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you "set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything" (sic) and edit your question with the full stack trace please?

Comment: Have you looked at similar [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387759/mule-transformerexception-an-invalid-return-type-class-b-was-specified-for-t?answertab=votes#tab-top) that have been answered?

Comment: Thanks for reply..When I debug then in logger I got output correct